# How do i convert paths that contain unc shares

Tags: java, windows, java-io, nio2

If user has not mounted a remote drive and is just using the `\\` syntax how do I convert such a path (`\\nas`) held in a String to a file in Java, sorry not really sure what you call this `\\` naming.

Also is this windows specific, can it also be `//`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass any valid file name to the constructor of a `File` and Java will handle that for you. e.g.

```
File input = new File("\\\\nas\\somefile.txt");
```

will work just fine. Note the escaped backslashs. Java can handle forward slashes just as well, so the above can be written as:

```
File input = new File("//nas/somefile.txt");
```

---

A filename like `\\nas\somefile.txt` is called a [UNC path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)#Uniform_Naming_Convention)

Comment: Does Java itself replace forward slashes with backslashes in a file path? If it instead relies on Windows to normalize the path, then note that local-device paths that begin with "\\?\" must use backslash as the path separator. Windows skips all normalization for this namespace, except to replace WinAPI "\\?\" with NTAPI "\??\".

Comment: Thanks, but I realize what is confusing me if that although you can create a File as described if you then call file.exists() it returns false, why would that be ?